# Oscillatory integral in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, scipy

I wrote the following code to plot the intensity of light exiting an optical components, which is basically a spherical Fourier integral on the incident field, so it has a Bessel function. The argument of which depends on the integrating variable (`x`) and the plotting variable (`r`).

```
from sympy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.special import jn

#constants
mm = 1
um = 1e-3 * mm
nm = 1e-6 * mm

wavelength = 532*nm
klaser = 2*np.pi / wavelength
waist = 3.2*mm
angle = 2 #degrees
focus = 125 * mm
ng = 1.5 # refractive index of axicon
upperintegration = 5

#integrals

def b(angle):
    radians = angle* np.pi/180
    return klaser * (ng-1) * np.tan(radians)

def delta(angle):
    return np.pi/(b(angle)*waist)    

def integrand(x, r): 
    return klaser/focus * waist**2 * np.exp(-x**2) * np.exp(-np.pi * 1j * x/delta(angle)) * jn(0, waist*klaser*r*x/focus) * x

def intensity1D(r):
    return np.sqrt(quad(lambda x: np.real(integrand(x, r)), 0, upperintegration)[0]**2 + quad(lambda x: np.imag(integrand(x, r)), 0, upperintegration)[0]**2)  

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

t = np.linspace(-3.5, 3.5, 25)
plt.plot(t, np.vectorize(intensity1D)(t))
```

The issue is that the plot changes drastically as I change the number of points I am using in my `linspace`, when I plot it.

I suspect this may be because of the oscillatory nature of the integral, so the step-size taken can dramatically change the value of the exponent and hence of the integral.

How does `quad` deal with this? Are there better methods to integrate numerically for this particular application?

Comment: Are you sure the formulae are correct? Usually you wouldn't have units like mm ending up in the exp or jn functions. (E.g. what is the exponential of a square millimeter??)

Comment: X is dimensionless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the call to [`quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html), set the `limit` argument to a large number.  This increases the maximum number subintervals that `quad` is allowed to use to estimate the integral.  When I use

```
def intensity1D(r):
    re = quad(lambda x: np.real(integrand(x, r)), 0, upperintegration, limit=8000)[0]
    im = quad(lambda x: np.imag(integrand(x, r)), 0, upperintegration, limit=8000)[0]
    return np.sqrt(re**2 + im**2)
```

and compute the function with the array `t` defined as

```
t = np.linspace(1.5, 3, 1000)
```

I get the following plot:

[image: plot]

(I also removed the line `from sympy import *`.  `sympy` does not appear to be used in
your script.)

You should always check the error estimate that is the second return value of `quad`.
For example:

```
In [14]: r = 3.0

In [15]: val, err = quad(lambda x: np.real(integrand(x, r)), 0, upperintegration, limit=8000)

In [16]: val
Out[16]: 2.975500141416676e-11

In [17]: err
Out[17]: 1.4590630152807049e-08
```

As you can see, the error estimate is much larger than the approximate integral.  The estimates returned by `quad` might be conservative, but a result with such a large error estimate should still be treated with caution.  Let's take a look at the corresponding imaginary part:

```
In [25]: val, err = quad(lambda x: np.imag(integrand(x, r)), 0, upperintegration, limit=8000)

In [26]: val
Out[26]: 0.0026492702707317257

In [27]: err
Out[27]: 1.4808416189183e-08
```

`val` is now orders of magnitude larger than the estimated error.  So when the magnitude of the complex value is computed in `intensity1D()`, we end up with estimated relative error on the order of 1e-5.  That may be sufficient for your calculation.

At the peak near r=2.1825, the magnitude of the error estimate is still small, and it is *much* smaller than the computed integral:

```
In [32]: r = 2.1825

In [33]: quad(lambda x: np.real(integrand(x, r)), 0, upperintegration, limit=8000)
Out[33]: (6.435730031424414, 8.801375195176556e-08)

In [34]: quad(lambda x: np.imag(integrand(x, r)), 0, upperintegration, limit=8000)
Out[34]: (-6.583055286038913, 9.211333259956749e-08)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are specific methods for integration of oscillatory integrands that actually increase in accuracy as the frequency increases. Filon and Levin methods are described here:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042706005929
Mathematica should use one of these if you specify LevinRule as method in
NIntegrate.  This is perhaps simple enough that -- if your integrand has the form, apparently common in optics calculations-- that you could even write a short program in your favorite efficient numerical programming language.
I suspect that using usual quadrature for oscillatory integrands is going to be painfully slow if you want to get accurate results.